# Difference between self.user and self.user_id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

1. I am a beginner of learning Django. When I read the code below, I have a few of questions.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Friendship(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='following_friendship_set',
    )
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='follower_friendship_set',
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        index_together = (
            ('from_user_id', 'created_at'),
            ('to_user_id', 'created_at'),
        )
        unique_together = (('from_user_id', 'to_user_id'), )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} followed {}'.format(self.from_user_id, self.to_user_id)
```

Why should use self.from_user_id and self.to_user_id not self.from_user and self.to_user in the **str** function? What is the difference?

2.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tweets.models import Tweet 



class NewsFeed(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    tweet = models.ForeignKey(Tweet, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        index_together = (('user', 'created_at'), )
        unique_together = (('user', 'tweet'), )
        ordering = ('user', '-created_at')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.created_at} inbox of {self.user}: {self.tweet}'
```

Why should use self.user and self.tweet not self.user_id and self.tweet_id in the **str** function above? Why doesn't the author use id in this part, but he does use id in part 1? I am so confused.

What is the difference between self.user and self.user_id?

Answer (score 0):

> Why should use `self.from_user_id` and `self.to_user_id` not `self.from_user` and `self.to_user` in the str function? What is the difference?

In the `__st__` method:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{} followed {}'.format(self.from_user_id, self.to_user_id)
```

the author uses `self.from_user_id`, this is the value the `ForeignKey` named `from_user` stores to refer to the user. In this case thus the *primary key* of the `User` object. It will thus return for example `'14 followed 25'`. Where *`14`* and *`25`* are the primary keys, the `id`s of the two `User` objects.

If we use `self.from_user` however, we fetch the related `User` object and the `.format(…)` function will call `str(…)` on that user. That will return how `__str__` has been defined on that model and for `User` it returns its `.username` so that will produce `'username1 followed username2'`. This last one is however more expensive: if we did not (yet) fetch the `user_from` and `user_to` objects for this `Friendship` object, it will thus make two extra queries to fetch the `user_from` and `user_to`.

As for the `unique_together` and `index_together`, it does not matter if you use `user_from` and `user_from_id`, since both eventually point to the same database column, and the database will thus make a unique constraint and an indexing.

> What is the difference between self.user and self.user_id?

`self.user` will fetch the `User` object the `ForeignKey` is referencing to, `self.user_id` will fetch the value the `ForeignKey` itself holds. `self.user` will thus make a query if it did not yet have that `.user`, whereas `self.user_id` is normally loaded when you load the records from the query.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: As the [documentation on **`unique_together`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/options/#unique-together) says, the `unique_together` constraint will likely become deprecated. The documentation advises to use the [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) from Django's [*constraint
> framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint).

Comment: But why does the author use self.user instead of self.user_id in the class NewsFeed of my second question? So I think it could be used return f'{self.created_at} inbox of {self.user_id}: {self.tweet_id}' ''', is that correct?

Comment: @danielsunck: to display the *username* of the user, not its primary key.

Comment: There it is, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Basics first :

- **id** is an identifier, **pk** is used too as for "primary key", both are indentifiers of an object. Usually we use `auto-increment` ids for users, so that every new user gets his own identifier.
- identifiers reference an object, user_id obviously refers to the user object. No extra info, just links to objects, usually an integer. My stack-overflow user.id is 3322400 and if you go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3322400 you'll see how an identifier is linked to a profile.
- user object is an instanced object of the user with all its information (with the above mentionned **id**entifier), it'll be used to get `user.name`, `user.mail`, and whatever property you gave your user model.
- `__str__(self)` is a method used to return a verbose representation of an object, it takes the object itself as a parameter, and will for instance `return f'{self.name} ({self.email})'`

So in the case of a friendship, your dev links both identifiers (id), and that'll be enough to identify both users and link them together.
3224000 is friend with 1352455, all good we can retrieve users profiles from those ids and link them.

In the case of an article, he wants his `__str__()` function to return more info: the date, user, tweet...

Then the `__str__()` function is mostly used for technical maintenance purposes IMO. Chances are this is solely used for a clean representation in django-admin.

Comment: gotcha, appreciate for your answer. Yeah, I need to consider what situations for using self.user or self.user_id. It depends on the need of the designing.